# multi client with server interaction using UDP protocol in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, networking, asp.net-web-api, network-programming, network-protocols

how can i differentiate client side and server side using UDP protocol class in .net.

i need to communicate with multiple clients to one server.

can anyone give me a idea.

Comment: Why are you using UDP? Unless you have a specific reason, you should be using TCP, as UDP does not provide reliable transfer, message ordering, etc. Also, there are hundreds, if not thousands of example network client/servers written for .NET. You're not asking any specific question.

Comment: i don't know whether UDP is better or TCP is better. why not use UDP?

Comment: I answered that ***exact*** question in the comment you've just responded to.

Comment: Because UDP is connectionless oriented. Always it no need to wait for client. That's why i took UDP protocol.

Comment: It completely depends on your application.